# React: passing audio data between two event handlers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a simple React application where you can record an audio clip and play it back. I can get the record functionality to work, but I'm not sure how to pass that data to my stop onclick. Here's what I have so far:

```js
export default class SongRecorder extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            record: false,
            songData: {}
        }
        this.recordSong = this.recordSong.bind(this);
        this.stopRecord = this.stopRecord.bind(this);
    }
    
    recordSong(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: true
        })
        .then(function(stream){
            const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            recorder.start();
            console.log(recorder.state);//this will tell us if recording is happening or not
            console.log("recorder started");
            //as recording happens, we need to collect the audio data with ondataavailable
            const chunks = [];
            recorder.ondataavailable = function(e){
                    chunks.push(e.data);
                }
            })

            this.setState({
                record: true,
            })
        }

    stopRecord(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    
        this.setState({
            record: false,
        })
    }
```

I tried to write an if statement in recordSong so that if record is set to false, it would stop the recorder and set songData to chunks, but I don't think that worked.

```js
function stop(recorder){
    if(this.state.record === false){
        recorder.stop();
        this.setState({
            songData: chunks
        })
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 1 more state named as `chunks` and then in response set chunks:

```
  recordSong(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: true
        })
        .then(function(stream){
            const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            recorder.start();
            console.log(recorder.state);//this will tell us if recording is happening or not
            console.log("recorder started");
            //as recording happens, we need to collect the audio data with ondataavailable
            recorder.ondataavailable = function(e){

                    this.setState({chunks:chunks.push(e.data)});
                }
            })

            this.setState({
                record: true,
            })
        }


function stop(recorder){
    if(this.state.record === false){
        recorder.stop();
        this.setState({
            songData: this.state.chunks
        })
    }
};
```